# Angular2: Router outlet not updating page if the component is same

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I am developing an application where I have configured router-outlet as below

```
{ path: 'dashboard/:id', component: DashboardComponent}
```

So when I click on the first link i.e dashboard/1 the page is updated. When I click on the second link dashboard/2, the page URL is updated but the view is not getting updated. But when I do a refresh it is getting updated.

My **Dashboardcomponent.html** is as below

```
<div    #coloneanchor></div>
    </div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<div   #coltwoanchor></div>
 </div>
```

My **Dashboardcomponent.ts**

```
@ViewChild('coloneanchor', { read: ViewContainerRef }) coloneanchor: any;
@ViewChild('coltwoanchor', { read: ViewContainerRef }) coltwoanchor: any;

this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
       this.id = param["id"];
        this.userService.getGadgets(this.id).subscribe(gadgets => {

switch(gadget)

case gadget1:
case gadget2:
```

Here I am creating two anchor points in my view. Once I get the id, I will pass it to an API to fetch the gadget and data and its column location. I loop through the gadgets and add them to the anchor points.

Comment: How does your DashboardComponent look like?

Comment: It takes the id and makes couple of API calls to load grids and charts. I see that DashboardComponent has to implement Reuse, but I think that doesn't exist anymore. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6910

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below in your `DashboardComponent`,

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.route.params.subscribe(param => {
       let id = param["id"];
       /// reload grid and charts...           
    })
  }
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: The grids and charts are getting appended to the previous view. Is there any way that the previous view be removed before adding this.

Comment: Won't be able to help untill I see the code.. how you are adding grid ..

Comment: Updated the question with more information and code. So basically the dashboard/2 gadgets are getting added to the view of dashboard/1, instead of displaying only dashboard/2 data.

Comment: Not very clear how you are adding gadgets, i believe you must be creating components dynamically and adding to `coloneanchor`, based upon your comment it seems you may not have cleared the ref, See [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html#!#clear-anchor) how to destroys all Views in this container.

Comment: It worked fine by clearing the anchor points.  I am actually creating the Routerlinks dynamically by doing <a [routerLink]="['/dashboard', dashboard.Id]" >{{ dashboard.Name }}</a> . Is there a way that the first link is automatically clicked/routed. I tried https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html but no success.